# Conditional rendering not displaying - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I have a log out button that I only want to show when the user is logged in.

I have created a function for this purpose and included the function in the return part of react but it's not working.

This is the function:

```
const ifloggedin = () => {
    if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('token')) {
      return null
} else {
return <li><a href="#contact" className="Contact" onClick={logout} to={"/"}>Log Out</a></li>
}
  }
```

This is how I am trying to render it in return:

```
        <div className="content">
          <li><a href="#hiw" className="Hiw" to={"/about"}>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing" className="Price" to={"/pricing"}>PRICING</a></li>
          <li><Link className="Faq" to={"/Faq"}>FAQ</Link></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" className="Contact" to={"/contact"}>CONTACT</a></li>
          {ifloggedin}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ifloggedin` is a function so you need to call it.

```
 <div className="content">
          <li><a href="#hiw" className="Hiw" to={"/about"}>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing" className="Price" to={"/pricing"}>PRICING</a></li>
          <li><Link className="Faq" to={"/Faq"}>FAQ</Link></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" className="Contact" to={"/contact"}>CONTACT</a></li>
          {ifloggedin()}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call ifloggedin as ifloggedin(), because it is an arrow function.
But in your case you are using it for conditional rendering so no need to write arrow function for that.

You can write it as normal function and use as ifloggedin()

```
 ifloggedin() {
if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('token')) {
  return null;
} else {
  return (
    <li>
      <a href="#contact" className="Contact" onClick={logout} to={'/'}>
        Log Out
      </a>
    </li>
  );
}
```